# Converting Array to HashMap using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, json, string, hashmap

I am writing a function to convert array to Map using Java 8 Stream.

```
    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(Object... entries) {
    // Requirements:
    // entries must be K1, V1, K2, V2, .... ( even length )
    if (entries.length % 2 == 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid entries");
    }

    // TODO
    Arrays.stream(entries).????
}
```

Valid usages

```
    Map<String, Integer> map1 = toMap("k1", 1, "k2", 2);

    Map<String, String> map2 = toMap("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2", "k3", "v3");
```

Invalid usages

```
    Map<String, Integer> map1 = toMap("k1", 1, "k2", 2, "k3");
```

Any helps?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your purpose for this? `Map.of` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(
                               Class<K> keyType, Class<V> valueType, Object... entries) {
    if(entries.length % 2 == 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid entries");
    return IntStream.range(0, entries.length/2).map(i -> i*2)
        .collect(HashMap::new,
                 (m,i)->m.put(keyType.cast(entries[i]), valueType.cast(entries[i+1])),
                 Map::putAll);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you realize it already exists?  It's been around since `Java 9`.

The following creates an immutable map of the keys and values.

```java
 Map<String, String> map2 = Map.of("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2", "k3", "v3");
```

For a mutable map do

```java
 Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>(Map.of("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2", "k3", "v3"));
```

Comment: The question explicitly mentions Java 8 so Java 9 is out of the scope of this question

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way

```
Map map = ArrayUtils.toMap(arrayName);
```

And you can import ArrayUtils from :

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
```

**Just include Apache JARs**